# Use mongofiles utility to access data inserted with Java GridFS API

Tags: java, mongodb, gridfs

I can successfully insert and retrieve data from MongoDB's GridFS in Java.  However, when I try to access that data on the command line using mongofiles, I can't find it.
The Java insertion code:

```
GridFS fs = new GridFS(Mongo.getStaticMongo("localhost:27017").getDB("myDb"), "myCollection");

try {
  GridFSInputFile inputFile = fs.createFile(content.getFile());
  inputFile.put(MONGO_KEY, content.getId().toString());   
  inputFile.save();
} catch (IOException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

The command line:

```
>mongofiles --host localhost:27017 -d myDb -c myCollection -vvvvvv list
Tue Nov 09 11:48:01 creating new connection to:localhost:27017
connected to: localhost:27017

>
```

Nothing comes back... where is the Java GridFS driver putting these files?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it would be beneficial to use a mongo admin utility to look in the mongo database and see what happened.  I use [phpMoAdmin](http://www.phpmoadmin.com/).  With it I can see all of the collections and items in the collections.  You can also edit the metadata too.  At least this way you can see things on a wider scale.

Comment: Great suggestion... thanks!  I would still be curious how to use mongofiles to see this also though.

Comment: My suspicion is that mongofiles uses the "standard" gridfs collections.  fs.files and fs.chunks.  I have not personally used mongo within java, but as long as your java code puts your files in these collections, the mongofiles tool should work ok.  Personally, I've used the php driver, which puts the files in the fs.files and fs.chunks collections by default.

Answer (score 1):

The `mongofiles` command line tool only works with the default 'fs' bucket.

There is an open JIRA item to address this: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1970